# How to generate an individual adjacency matrix from a group adjacency matrix, in r

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix representing species by species interactions (a tri-trophic chain):

```
mat = matrix(c(0,1,0,
               0,0,1,
               0,0,0), nrow=3, byrow = T,
             dimnames = list(c("sp1","sp2","sp3"),
                             c("sp1","sp2","sp3")))
```

and a dataframe that contains the species' abundances:

```
comm = t(data.frame(sp1=100,
                    sp2=20,
                    sp3=5))
```

Using the above, is there an efficient way to create an individual based adjacency matrix?

```
in.mat = matrix(0, nrow = sum(comm),
               ncol = sum(comm),
            byrow = T,
            dimnames = list(c(rep("sp1",100),rep("sp2",20),rep("sp3",5)),
                            c(rep("sp1",100),rep("sp2",20),rep("sp3",5))))
```

So that all individuals of sp3 are connected with all individuals from sp2 and those with all individuals of sp1.
I would appreciate any pointers, I have not managed to find similar questions, perhaps because I am not using the appropriate terms.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, can you please elaborate a bit on the desired shape of `in.mat`? Why are you using `sum(comm)`? `nrow(comm)`, `ncol(comm)` is not what you are after?

Comment: The desired output is a square matrix of all 125 individuals interacting based on the group (sp1,sp2,sp3) they belong to.

Comment: Note that comm is a matrix, not a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate we will use a smaller example shown in the Note at the end but the same code would work with the example in the question.  No packages are used except as indicated.

**1)**  Expand the names into nms and then use subscripting.

```
nms <- rep(rownames(comm), comm)
mat[nms, nms]
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
##  [1,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
##  [2,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
##  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
##  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
##  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
##  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

**2)** Another approach using nms as above is to use one of these:

```
outer(nms, nms, function(x, y) mat[cbind(x, y)])

outer(nms, nms, Vectorize(function(x, y) mat[x, y]))

sapply(nms, function(y) sapply(nms, function(x) mat[x, y]))

library(listcompr)
gen.matrix(mat[x, y], x = nms, y = nms)
```

The eList or comprehenr packages could also be used.

## Note

```
# input
sp <- paste0("sp", 1:3)
mat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0), 3, dimnames = list(sp, sp))
comm <- matrix(2:4, 3, dimnames = list(sp, NULL))

mat
##     sp1 sp2 sp3
## sp1   0   1   0
## sp2   0   0   1
## sp3   0   0   0

comm
##     [,1]
## sp1    2
## sp2    3
## sp3    4
```

Comment: Wow, this not only solves my issue, it shows me what my reprex should have looked like... Many thanks